# Making class vars available to external itemRenderer classes

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I made a custom itemRenderer, and need to access a variable in my Project file (mxml). How can I make my public var available in the custom itemRenderer file?

```
    public function lang_f(trans_short:String):String{
        if(outerDocument.language == "de"){
            ...
        }
    }
```

Greetings
Markus

Comment: What kind of variable?  Is this for all item renderers?  What does the variable do?

Comment: public var language:String; it saves the actual language of the user

Comment: Why is language important in the item renderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go along with Constantiner's answer, if you **still** need to access that variable, you can access the variable in your itemRenderer using `outerDocument`:

`outerDocument.myVariableName`

Comment: Thanks for your hint, unfortunately It didn't work: 1120: Access of undefined property Bindable outerDocument

Comment: @Markus Can you post the portion of your code that's not working?

Comment: @Markus If your ItemRenderer is a custom component, you may want to try `parentDocument` instead of `outerDocument`.

Comment: This results in the following error: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did a work around by handing a variable over to the itemRenderer while creating it.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't access outer document data from within item renderer. It breaks OOP principles such as low coupling etc. You should either set this data to item renderer with data from data provider or extend your list based component to instantiate renderers with that data. And don't think about MXML component as files. The file structure is just a form of representation. You'd better think MXML files as classes or components — in terms of application structure.

Comment: If you provide some code there can be a solution without going dark side of the Force :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the variable defined in main file of your application ? If that's the case you can access is using FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME 
However I agree with Constantiner. This violation of OOP principles. But I hope that solves your problem.